# Fixed header above Ionic 2 content / navbar With page transitions

Tags: ionic-framework

I want to have a fixed logo in the Ionic2 framework. I have transitions between pages and the header and pages gets slid in. I want to know if I can keep the header / logo a constant above anything on the page.

```html
<ion-header>
    <a  (click)="goToRoot()" ><img src="assets/img/topBar-iPad.png" alt=""/></a>
</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>
 </ion-content>
```

I have tried it with the toolbar this doesn't work either.

Comment: Do you find any solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

If you want put an image in header, you can use this code:

```
<ion-header>
<ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Title</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
        <img height="35px" width="35px" src="assets/img/topBar-iPad.png">
    </ion-buttons>
</ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

Comment: This is not what the question asked at all, it asked how to fix the header during page transitions.

Answer (score 0):

This might get a bit tricky if you app becomes a bit more complex over time, however what you can do is add your `<ion-header>` element to your `app.html` file found in `src -> app`.

That sets it at top level above the pages you are navigation to.

If your app does become complex over time where only in some cases you want the toolbar to be fixed at the top you might need to either create a custom component based on the  element or pass in a `*ngIf` ( or `[hidden]=""`) and then write logic to support its visibility.